# coffeescript-ing a nested for loop

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have this nested for loop in javascript and i cant put it into coffeescript.
It doesn't seem like supporting these type of nested / dependent for loops.

```
    for (index = 1; index < colorId.length; ++index) {
      for (index2 = 0; index2 < index; ++index2) {
        if(colorId[index] == colorId[index2]){
          colorId[index2] = (projects[index].id%9 + 1) * 10 + (projects[index].id%5)
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show your (attempted) coffescript version?

Comment: `for i in [1...colorId.length]`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
colorId=['x','y','z']

for index in [1...colorId.length]
  for index2 in [0...index]
    console.log index, index2
```

Works for me, producing:

```
1 0
2 0
2 1
```

In the `for ... in ...` construct, the length of the array is evaluated *before* entering the loop. So it won't work as expected if you somehow change the length of your array during processing.

For that kind of things, you should use a `while` instead.